# How to prove that $i^\vee:X^\vee\rightarrow Y^\vee$ is dominant?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In my case $X$ is an abelian variety, $Y$ is an abelian subvariety of $X$, $i: Y\hookrightarrow X$ is the inclusion map,so we have $i^\vee:X^\vee\cong Pic^0X\rightarrow Y^\vee\cong Pic^0Y$, the dual morphism of $i$, which corresponds to the pullback $i^*:Pic^0X\rightarrow Pic^0Y$.

Now, I would like to prove that this is dominant. I guess that it´s even surjective. But how can I prove this? Given $\mathcal{L}\in Pic^0Y$, how to construct $\mathcal{G}\in Pic^0X$ such that $i^*\mathcal{G}\cong\mathcal{L}$? Does it work with $\mathcal{G}=i_*\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: $i_*\mathcal{L}$ is probably not a line bundle.

Comment: Thank you! And do you have an idea of how to prove that $i^*$ is dominant?